# Yii2, change permission on backend/web/assets

Tags: permissions, yii2, assets

I am using Yii2, advanced applications.

Is there a way to change the directory permission of the folders created in  the assets folder `backend/web/assets`.

By default it is `775`, I want to make them `755`

I want to make this change, maybe from Yii config and not from the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You should simply change AssetManager property [`dirMode`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetmanager.html#$dirMode-detail) in your config file :

> `$dirMode` : The permission to be set for newly generated asset directories. This value will be used by PHP chmod() function. No umask will be applied. Defaults to 0775, meaning the directory is read-writable by owner and group, but read-only for other users.

e.g. :

```
'assetManager' => [
    'dirMode' => 0755,
    // ...
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach for Yii2 advanced:

Go to your project root directory, open this file `your-yii2-project/environments/index.php` and see given permissions:

```
return [
    'Development' => [
        'path' => 'dev',
        'setWritable' => [
            'backend/runtime',
            'backend/web/assets',
            'frontend/runtime',
            'frontend/web/assets',
        ],
        'setExecutable' => [
            'yii',
            'tests/codeception/bin/yii',
        ],
        'setCookieValidationKey' => [
            'backend/config/main-local.php',
            'frontend/config/main-local.php',
        ],
    ],
```